# How to share socket with asyncio in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, python-asyncio

I need to use `asyncio` with `os.fork()` method for sharing socket between subprocess.

There is a `heavy_jobs()` function in `data_received()` callback, which will occupy a lot of CPU time.

```
import asyncio

class EchoClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, message, loop):
        self.message = message
        self.loop = loop

    def data_received(self, data):
        heavy_jobs()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
message = 'Hello World!'
coro = loop.create_connection(lambda: EchoClientProtocol(message, loop),
                              '127.0.0.1', 8000)
loop.run_until_complete(coro)
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

In traditional method, we could use `fork()` to share socket between subprocess and parent:

```
bind(...);
listen(...);
pid = fork();
```

So, how could I do the same thing in `asyncio`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently asyncio does not support fork while the event loop is running (https://bugs.python.org/issue21998). You must fork and then create the loop. A simple EchoClient with two processes:

```
import asyncio
import os
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 7777))
pid = os.fork()

class EchoClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, message, loop):
        self.message = message
        self.loop = loop

    def data_received(self, data):
        print('Received in %s' % pid)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
message = 'Hello World!'
coro = loop.create_connection(lambda: EchoClientProtocol(message, loop), sock=sock)
loop.run_until_complete(coro)
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

And simple test - run `nc -k -l 7777`, then start the client (code above).

If you also want to write a server, just change `connect` with `socket.bind` and `socket.listen` and of course `asyncio.create_server`

Comment: Thank you, it's really helpful